# Count function execution

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner with JavaScript so please be patient.

I'm trying to write a function which changes color of an object every time  when it is called.

Here is the  code:

```
var i = 0;
    var colors=["blue","red","green","yellow","lime"];
    function changeColor(a, colors) {
        if (i==4) {
            i=0;
         }
         a.style.color=colors[i];
         i++;
         }
```

I need a counter so that it can iterate through the *arrays (colors)*, when it's called.
So, how to update the globally declared *variable i* through *changeColor* function. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Exactly how you have already done it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine. I'm suggesting a shorter way to iterate i from 0 to 4 using i = (i +1)%5 It will return 0 when i +1 is 5

```
var i = 0;
var colors=["blue","red","green","yellow","lime"];
function changeColor(a, colors) {
    i = (i +1)%colors.length;
    a.style.color=colors[i];
}
```

As @guest271314 suggested below, I change the number to colors.length to make it more flexible to the size of the colors array.

Comment: _"Your code should work fine. I'm suggesting a shorter way to iterate i from 0 to 3 "_ Note, the array `.length` at code at Question is `5`

Answer (score 0):

To reach `"lime"` at index `4` then `"blue"` at index `0` you can set the `color` value before `if` condition and use an `else` statement

```js
var i = 0;
var colors = ["blue", "red", "green", "yellow", "lime"];

function changeColor(colors) {
  document.body.style.color = colors[i];
  if (i == 4) {
    i = 0;
  } else {
    i++;
  }
}

setInterval(function() {
  document.body.textContent = i;
  changeColor(colors);
}, 1500)
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  font-weight: 36px;
}
```